# Doob Decomposition Theorem in Williams is working backward? Unique modulo indistinguishability?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

Probability with Martingales

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

This is my understanding of what is going on in the proof above:

1. We first assume $X$ has such Doob Decomposition in order to figure out what $A$ to use in order to prove the Doob Decomposition.
2. The details of the proof are left to the reader namely:
3. The proof that $A$ is previsible (obvious).
4. The proof that $M = X - X_0 - A$ is a martingale null at 0.
5. The details of unique modulo indistinguishability

Is that right?

How can we prove #5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 5.: The key is this: A previsible martingale is constant in time. In more detail, if $X$ admits a second decomposition $X_n=X_0+M'_n+A'_n$ then by subtracting you find that $M_n-M'_n$($=A'_n-A_n$) is both a martingale and previsible, hence constant in time a.s., whence $M_n-M'_n=M_0-M'_0=0-0=0$ for all $n$, a.s.

Comment: John Dawkins, how do you know 1 $M_n - M_n'$ is a martingale? 2. $M_n - M_n' = M_0 - M_0'$ ? 3. $M_0 - M_0' = 0$ ? 4. $P(M_n = M_n', A_n = A_n' \ \forall n \ge 1) = 1$ given $P(M_n = M_n', A_n = A_n') = 1 \ \forall n \ge 1$?

Comment: 1. Because of the linearity of conditional expectation, the difference of two martingales is a martingale. 2. This follows because $M-M'$ is a predictable martingale, hence constant in time. 3. $M_0=0$ and $M'_0=0$ is required of $M$ and $M'$ ("M is a martingale null at 0"). 4. See my answer to your other post.